# JEE use JNDI with JDBC and auth Application level

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jndi, tomcat8

For simplicity we have Tomcat 8.0.27. Under the IDE create a web project.

In web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/tablemanager</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In context.xml(This under tomcat)

I prefer this way instead the double reference  https://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

```
<Resource
      name="jdbc/tablemanager"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      initialSize="34"
      maxActive="377"
      maxIdle="233"
      minIdle="89"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="34000"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
      username="tablemanager"
      password="tablemanager"
      driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.3:3306/tablemanager?allowMultiQueries=true"
 />
```

In the page

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/tablemanager");

try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {
```

This work very well if the user that access to the DB is located at application level.

Is there a strict DB user management where each user has it row level grant? That is, instead of using a Container auth can the app:

- Use application level authorization. Like:

  Connection conn = ds.getConnection("tablemanager", "tablemanager");
- Can the connection retrieved from a pool (I suspect that this is not possible because the username and password are used in Tomcat jdbc pool to test the query)
- If pool is not suitable can I define a resource and use it for the connection.

I have done some tests

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB2 Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<Resource
    name="jdbc/db2"
    auth="Application"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.3:3306/tablemanager?allowMultiQueries=true"
 />
```

With this config when I do

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/db2");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection("tablemanager", "tablemanager");
```

I get

> Not supported by BasicDataSource

Comment: You get it thrown by which line of code? NB `BasicDataSource` is a pooling DS, part of Apache DBCP or whatever it's called, I believe, which you get free with Tomcat.

Comment: @user207421 Connection conn = ds.getConnection("tablemanager", "tablemanager"); give me that erro . I'm looking if is possible to create DS(data source) inside app srv and connect giving at use time the user and password.